# How to return the number of same elements on same index position when comparing two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays:

```
array([2,3,4,4,1])
```

and

```
array([3,3,5,4,1])
```

I want to return the number of similar values at similar index positions. In this case this should be 3, is this possible with a single numpy operation? I know how to do it with a for loop but I rather not do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.sum()`

```
l1 = np.array([2, 3, 4, 4, 1])
l2 = np.array([3, 3, 5, 4, 1])

>>> np.sum(l1 == l2)
3

>> l1 == l2
array([False,  True, False,  True,  True])
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I need!